# How can i get Contact list from mobile?

Tags: php, windows-mobile

I am developing web application which is need to get the contact information from mobile(iPhone,Noakia, etc...).My application is in PHP.Please advice me over this issues

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to do in PHP. PHP is working server side while your mobile phone operates client side.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way would be for an ActiveX style script to run on the Windows Mobile device which then sends the data back to PHP. You'll probably be unable to do this under Javascript because of the sandbox: and ActiveX, in my eyes at least, should be similarly sandboxed (as you don't want sites arbitrarily getting your contact information).

If the phone has a sync system (such as the iPhone's contact list sync item), you may be able to utilise that for people to sync to your app.